# jQueryの変数のコロン

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

jQueryでJSONオブジェクトを扱うときに､例えば`hoge:fuga`みたいな､コロンが途中に入っている要素はどのようにして扱えばいいのでしょうか｡

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj["hoge:fuga"]`でアクセスできます。

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"hoge:fuga": "piyo"}');
alert(obj["hoge:fuga"]);
```

Comment: @h2so4様
回答ありがとう御座います!